# Temporary (just 2-3 second) 5V Power Backup for Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, 5v, ups

I have built a portable computer today, with a Raspberry Pi and a Motorola Lapdock. Everything seems perfect. Except, when I close the lid, power goes down for 1 or 2 seconds and comes back and this shuts down my Raspberry Pi.

Can you suggest me a solution for this little power problem? Maybe a circuit with capacitor or something like that?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You may have already touched on a simple solution to your problem. A large value but low voltage capacitor.

Comment: Try just a capacitor by itself, close to the RPi power input.

Comment: Raspberry Pi units can draw a lot of current (amperes) depending on what's connected to the USB connectors. I suggest either a 'power bank' with 'pass through' charging capability- available for < $20, or (maybe) you could change what the lapdock does when the lid is closed to nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Capacitor:**

The voltage on a 1  Farad capacitor will drop 1V in 1 second with 1A load.
So eg for 100 mA load and 3 seconds holdup for 1V drop you need
1F x 3s x 0.1A ~= 0.3F.

More mA or time or less voltage drop  = more capacitance.
eg for 0.1V drop and 500 mA you need ~= 15F.
So a supercap rated at > 5V will probably be needed.
Typically supercap Vrating is < 5V so you need 2 in series with double the final capacitance each. ie

> 1.2F each for the first example and
>   30F each for the 2nd example.

**Battery:**

An easier method is to use a battery with a Schottky isolation diode or an active switch.    If you can be certain to not draw battery power except when laptop dock switching the AA Alkaline batteries will last a long while (years for several switchings per day).
Or you could use eg NimH batteries recharged by the 5V supply "with due design".

**Flywheel:**

Just for fun - DC motor with flywheel that becomes a generator at changeover time. Not very practical, but fun.

Once upon a time the big boys did something roughly similar, for different reasons with [Ward Leonard sets](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=ward+leonard&num=100&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv_OKKxYLOAhUEopQKHS0EBHcQsAQILQ&biw=1280&bih=717&dpr=1.5). (Motor driving generator driving motor driving ...).